# Can ProGuard change access modifers to package-private?

Tags: java, proguard, android-proguard

Is it possible, using ProGuard, to move all your obfuscated classes to a named package and change their public or protected methods or member variables to package protected?

I know you can use -repackageclasses to move the classes, but it seems -allowaccessmodification changes access modifiers to public.
The goal is to prevent users of my library from being able to use anything but the exposed public API. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I meant package-private not package-protected.

Comment: Might be worth setting up a Hello World project with ProGuard enabled and sharing on GitHub? It'll reduce friction to help as people can fork and try their ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, and I don't think you should. When classes are compiled and code won't change, relaxing the object/method qualifiers won't alter access patterns; in other words, an object that successfully called a `protected` method/object would still have access to it if the qualifier is changed to `public`. The opposite is not true; a `public` object/method that turns `protected` could become invisible/inaccessible to the calling object all of a sudden - rendering badly compiled code. I have used ProGuard before, but my answer is based on logic rather than experimentation.

Comment: I meant package-private not protected. I assume (I could be wrong) that we could create an aar that was sealed like a jar. If that were the case then any classes not in the aar could not access the package-private members.